# XSLT: XTSE0010: An fo:block element must not contain an xsl:param element

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am passing a few parameters from Java code into my XSL style sheet for generating the PDF using XSL:FO, but I get this error:

```
XTSE0010: An fo:block element must not contain an xsl:param element
```

This is my stylesheet (partly):

```
 <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientId"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientName" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientAddress" />
        ,<xsl:value-of select="reportContent/client/clientTown" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/reportInterval/startDate"/>
         - <xsl:value-of select="reportContent/reportInterval/endDate"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block page-break-inside="auto">
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block/>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <xsl:for-each select="reportContent/batch">
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="3px">
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:param name="clientId" />
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</fo:flow>
```

Is there any way I can use parameters inside my `xsl:fo` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use the values of parameters passed on from Java to XSLT inside the `<fo:block>` tags, I had to *initialise* the parameter right after the `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag end inside my .xsl file:

```
<xsl:param name="clientId" />
```

And then after use it inside my *:fo* tag like this:

```
<fo:block>
   <xsl:value-of select="$clientId"/>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Yes, the `xsl:param` declaration for a parameter passed to the stylesheet has to be a 'top-level' element (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-top-level), i.e., be a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` element.